# Pasar un numpy array de 3D a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Necesito pasar un array guardado como np.save("........npy) y recuperado con np.load(".....,npy)
con este shape: (2367, 16, 100000) a un dataframe de 2367 filas y 16 columnas, cada array tiene 100000 datos tipo float.

He probado esto:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=df, columns=["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", 
                  "12", "13", "14", "15", "16"])
```

El error que me da es este:

```
 ValueError: Shape of passed values is (16, 100000), indices imply (16, 16)
```

Entiendo el error pero no sé cómo hacerlo bien.

Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida!

Comment: ¿Cual es la salida esperada? ¿Un dataframe de arrays?, es decir, ¿cada celda debe tener como valor el array de 100000 elementos?

Comment: Si, cada celda debería tener un array de 100000 elementos float. 2367 filas, 16 columnas y cada celda el array de 100000 floats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar [pandas.DataFrame.from_records](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df_data = np.random.rand(2367, 16, 10)

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(df_data, columns=map(str, range(1, 17)))
```

En el ejemplo he reducido el numero de elementos de los arrays para no ocupar 20 Gb de memoria...

El resultado será:

```
>>> df.shape
(2367, 16)

>>> df["1"].iat[0]
array([0.99974856, 0.49090714, 0.64071117, 0.91462377, 0.97951781,
       0.84776852, 0.78123668, 0.21983271, 0.14427836, 0.75586828])
```

Comment: Funciona perfectamente, muchas gracias!!